# I factory reset my hudl2, and now it "can't connect to the Internet"

Tags: factory-reset

I was given an old Tesco Hudl2 recently (Model No. HTFA4B), and the one of the first things I did - perhaps unwisely - was to do a factory reset on it.

Now, after choosing my WiFi connection, it tells me:

> **Couldn't access internet**
>
> An internet connection is needed to setup your hudl.  Please check your WiFi settings or connect to a different network.

[This page](https://forums.moneysavingexpert.com/discussion/5968481/tesco-hudl-do-not-factory-reset) suggests the update server (rather than the "internet") is probably down.

A packet capture seems to suggest it's connecting to https://device.mobile.tesco.com/, but the certificate there expired on 26 June.

A [thread](https://www.modaco.com/forums/topic/382204-hudl-2-connects-to-wifi-but-tesco-update-server-not-switched-on/?page=11) at Modaco may have more information, but the forums have been down for at least the last couple of days.

Comment: If it is really the certificate try to change the system date to a date before the certificate had expired.

Comment: Good suggestion.  I don't think I have the option to set the clock sadly.  I'm not sure it's doing an NTP query from the packet capture, but maybe if I run the battery down..  I'm guessing I may have to spoof an NTP server?

Comment: Do you have back up of phone. Specifically your profile backup. Try to restore your profile. It will also restore your network internet WIFi setting.
Do you able to connect other wifi network.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  It's not a WiFi problem though - the device can connect to the Internet, but because it can't talk to the update server it shows a misleading error message.  (Hudl is a tablet by the way, not a phone..)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've managed to work around this for a Hudl 1 by setting the date to before 26 June.  I had to escape the set-up wizard and then find a way to get into the settings app.  I don't know if a similar set of steps will work for the Hudl 2?

[My write up is here](https://rob.themayfamily.me.uk/hudl)

Comment: Thanks!  I guess the main tricks are: get from the keyboard into Chrome via the Privacy Policy; search for the "Open Settings (shortcut to setting)" app; install and open it to change the date.  I hit some miscellaneous hurdles, but I think most were solved with patience or more reboots.

Comment: @mwfearnley - can you confirm that you made this work with a Hudl 2 as weel - if so then I'll update my instructions to include that it can work for a HUdl 2 as well.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I can confirm that your steps worked for a Hudl 2. Any problems I had might have been due to not following the instructions carefully enough. The principles were certainly sound. The big breakthrough was learning I could get to a web browser from the keyboard!

Comment: Saved us there, thanks!